# spring war file deployment failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat7

I'm working with a Spring Boot Application. Everything works fine on my local desktop and I wanted to deploy it on my tomcat 7 webserver. I created with maven a .war file.
This .war file contains:

- 1 SpringBootApplication class
- application.properties
- log4j.properties

The Spring Boot Application class does nothing else than executing a shellscript on the same server my tomcat is running on.

When deploying the .war project I receive this errormessage:

```
[root@server proj]# tc7 instance_stopstart
INFO: Stopping and starting instance ...
INFO: Stopping server 'server1'
INFO: Server 'server1' stopped successfully
INFO: Starting server 'server1', waiting a maximum of 60 seconds
ERROR: startup failed (for details see catalina.out)
```

the catalina.out file looks like this

```
2018-10-25 11:55:37.201  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain       : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@75608dd7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6a4458a8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e549d52, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@373ff6e, org.flowable.ui.common.filter.FlowableCookieFilter@776e042e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2d2eb95f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@172a1fa5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@10d2b4a0, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1971a781, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5222b1fe, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5015450e]
2018-10-25 11:55:37.251  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.w.EndpointLinksResolver        : Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-10-25 11:55:37.266  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/flowable],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.266  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/auditevents],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.266  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/beans],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.267  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.267  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/conditions],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.267  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/configprops],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.267  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/env/{toMatch}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.267  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/env],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.268  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.268  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.268  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers/{name}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.269  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers/{name}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.269  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/heapdump],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.270  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/threaddump],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.270  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/metrics],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.270  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.270  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/scheduledtasks],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.270  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/httptrace],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.270  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/mappings],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.271  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-10-25 11:55:37.333  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-10-25 11:55:37.335  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-10-25 11:55:37.343  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [flowable-ui-task:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-10-25 11:55:37.351  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Starting beans in phase -20
2018-10-25 11:55:37.352  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-10-25 11:55:37.353  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Starting beans in phase 20
2018-10-25 11:55:37.385  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.f.u.t.c.Bootstrapper                   : Migrated 0 app deployments
2018-10-25 11:55:37.391  INFO 2031620 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.f.u.t.a.FlowableTaskApplication        : Started FlowableTaskApplication in 12.933 seconds (JVM running for 17.603)
```

Is there a possibility to define where the error is or am I doing an obvious mistake?

Comment: There is no error in this log. Can you have a look at the other tomcat log files?

Comment: which other tomact log files?

Comment: sometimes tomcat is configured to write errors in a separate log file.

Comment: Simon is right, can you check the logs folder inside your tomcat folder ?

Comment: I do have catalina.out, access_log and that's it.. nothing more. but I fixed this problem..

Comment: I created a rest service out of it (it actually was some kind of a rest service - I'm new to this technology) and I let it build through maven again and it worked